# How to detect when a process doesnt exist anymore?

Tags: c++, winapi

Trying to find a way to get notified when a process doesn't exist anymore, other way than constantly checking for something like`"if process exist"`.

Which options do i have?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can open a process with [`OpenProcess`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-openprocess) and use [`WaitForSingleObject`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/synchapi/nf-synchapi-waitforsingleobject) on that process. The function `WaitForSingleObject` will return as soon as the target process no longer exists. However, you will have to have one thread in a constant wait state if you want your program to be immediately notified when the target process no longer exists.

An alternative would be to call [`RegisterWaitForSingleObject`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-registerwaitforsingleobject), which will automatically create a thread for you (or use an existing thread in the thread pool), which will wait on the process and will call the callback function that you specified, as soon as the target process no longer exists.

Comment: Make sure to request the `SYNCHRONIZE` access right when calling `OpenProcess`, and not pass any other access rights.